# Performance Dynamic SQL vs Temporary Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering if copying an existing Table into a Temporary Table results in a worse performance compared to Dynamic SQL.

To be concrete i wonder if i should expect a different performance between the following two SQL Server stored procedures:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE UsingDynamicSQL
    (
      @ID INT ,
      @Tablename VARCHAR(100)
    )
 AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
        SELECT  @SQL = 'Insert into Table2 Select Sum(ValColumn) From '
                + @Tablename + ' Where ID=' + @ID
        EXEC(@SQL)
    END

    CREATE PROCEDURE UsingTempTable
        (
          @ID INT ,
          @Tablename Varachar(100)
        )
    AS
        BEGIN
            Create Table #TempTable (ValColumn float, ID int)
            DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
            SELECT  @SQL = 'Select ValColumn, ID From ' + @Tablename
                    + ' Where ID=' + @ID
            INSERT  INTO #TempTable
                    EXEC ( @SQL );
            INSERT  INTO Table2
                    SELECT  SUM(ValColumn)
                    FROM    #TempTable;
            DROP TABLE #TempTable;
        END
```

I'm asking this since I'm currently using a Procedure build in the latter style where i create many Temporary Tables in the beginning as simple extracts of existing Tables and am afterwards working with these Temporary Tables.
Could I improve the performance of the stored procedure by getting rid of the Temporary Tables and using Dynamic SQL instead? In my opinion the Dynamic SQL Version is a lot uglier to programm - therefore i used Temporary Tables in the first place.

Comment: Can't you test both of those sp's?

Comment: Before you used aesthetics to determine your programming approach, did you read what Microsoft had to say about table variables?  I found the part about number of rows to be interesting.

Comment: The answer to this depends on a lot of things including the size of the table variables. Ifyou have a lot records, you are often better off using temptables which can be indexed. I am more concerned as to why you would want to pass in a table name. That speaks to a design problem. And BTW never use float if you are doing mathmatical calculations, it is not an exact value and you will introduce rounding errors.

Comment: I have to agrtee with @DanBracuk. aesthetics are a horrible way to do SQl coding.

Comment: But they both use EXEC ( @SQL );.  You really think copy the data to #TEMP to run the query is faster?  How would that be faster?

Comment: This might be interesting: http://www.syntaxwarriors.com/2012/t-sql-table-variable-vs-temporary-table/

Comment: This was never supposed to be a question about Temporary Tables and Table variables.

I implemented both and they run just as fast as the other.
With a more complex code i also did this comparison - In my case saving the table extracts first (using Dyn SQL) as temporary tables and afterwards writing select queries using these temporary tables performed twice as fast as doing everything in dynamic SQL.
Therefore, when applied on my longer procedure the second variant was twice as fast but i guess this is highly dependend on the specific procedure...

Comment: Did the second run faster on the posted code?

Comment: No, both ran equally fast.

Answer (score 1):

Table variables suffer performance problems because the query optimizer always assumes there will be exactly one row in them.  If you have table variables holding > 100 rows, I'd switch them to temp tables.

Using dynamic sql with `EXEC(@sql)` instead of `exec sp_executesql @sql` will prevent the query plan from being cached, which will probably hurt performance.

However, you are using dynamic sql on both queries.  The only difference is that the second query has the unnecessary step of loading to a table variable first, then loading into the final table.  Go with the first stored procedure you have, but switch to sp_executesql.

Comment: My Actual Procedure is way more complex. Therefore it is simpler to use dynamic SQL once in the beginning and afterwards work with Tablevariables instead of working with Dynamic SQL in the entire Procedure.
My Table Variables are small (about 70 rows). I already rewrote my procedure using Temporary Tables instead of Table Variables but the Runtime stayed exactly the same. However, rewriting my Procedure to use Dynamic SQL will take a lot of time so i first wanted to ask if i could expect an improvement.

Comment: Just because the runtime stayed the same doesn't mean using temp tables wouldn't be an improvement.  Turn I/O Stats on and look at CPU and reads.

Comment: Where is the OP using a table variable?

Comment: He has changed it to a table variable in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the posted query the temporary table is an extra write.
It is not going to help.

Don't just time a query look at the query plan.
If you have two queries the query plan will tell you the split.

And there is a difference between a table variable and temp table
The temp table is faster - the query optimizer does more with a temp table

A temporary table can help in a few situations

1. The output from a select is going to be used more than once
   You materialize the output so it is only executed once
   Where you see this is with a an expensive CTE that is evaluated many times
   People of falsely think a CTE is just executed once - no it is just syntax
2. The query optimizer need help
   An example
   You are doing a self join on a large table with multiple conditions and some of conditions eliminate most of the rows
   A query to a #temp can filter the rows and also reduce the number of join conditions

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else that you always need to test both... I'm putting it in an answer here so it's more clear.

If you have an index setup that is perfect for the final query, going to temp tables could be nothing but extra work.

If that's not the case, pre-filtering to a temp table may or may not be faster.
You can predict it at the extremes -  if you're filtering down from a million to a dozen rows, I would bet it helps.
But otherwise it can be genuinely difficult to know without trying.

I agree with you that maintenance is also an issue and lots of dynamic sql is a maintenance cost to consider.